# Unexpected output from iterator when iteration performed on given collection object

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Shouldn't be the output of below code 012345678 ? When I run it output is 02468. Could you please help me to understand this.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.Iterator;

    import java.util.List;

    public class CollectionArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> num = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        num.add(i);

    }
    //System.out.println(num);

    int int1=9;
    Integer in = new Integer(int1);

    Iterator itr = num.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
        if(itr.next()== in) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this statement `System.out.println(itr.next());` you were skipping elements.
And **==** is used for reference comparison and not for content comparison. So your if block was never executing and **9** was never being deleted. You should do like below:

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = num.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Integer val = (Integer) itr.next();
    if(val.equals(in)) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of mistake in your code, i will list out all of them below

1. You are skipping up the elements by using `itr.next()` during the print `System.out.println(itr.next());`
2. You are creating new `Integer` object with value `9` and comparing their reference instead of value, which is returning `false`

**For Example :** Below `i1` and `i2` are two `Integer` objects having same values but they are two different objects pointing to different references. So the `==` operator returns `false`

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
Integer i2 = new Integer(10);  

System.out.println(i1==i2);   //false
```

3. So you can simply use `equal` to compare the values in `Integers` objects and only print the values when it is not `equal` to `9` by using `else` block

**Code :**

```
   int int1=9;
   Integer in = new Integer(int1);    //don't use like this, it is deprecated and no need of it

    Iterator<Integer> itr = num.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Integer res = itr.next();
        if(res.equal(in)) {
            itr.remove();
        }else {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
```

4. But you don't need to create `Integer` object, you can simple use `equals` where java does [auto boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for you and also you generic type objects like `Iterator<Integer>` and `List<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();`

**Code :**

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = num.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Integer res = itr.next();
        if(res.equals(int1)) {   // or == operator will work for primitive int types 
            itr.remove();
        }else {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you called iterator twice in loop causing to skip elements. you should refactor code to call next only once to get the expected output as below.

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
 int num = itr.next();
    System.out.println(num);
    if(num == in) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```